# Get XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com as a service account

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I am new to Google Analytics and I am trying to retrieve Google Analytics data using Pentaho Data Integration (CE 6.0) by following [Pentaho Google Analytics](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Google+Analytics)

It says I need to create a service account to get the data. On the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) I at location Google API manager --> Credentials --> Create service account

Now when I try to create a new service account, it by default assigns XXXXX@YYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Instead of this I must have **XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com**

Can someone please share any insight on how to get XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com as a service account email?

Answer (score 0):

The old format for service accounts was

> XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com

the new format for service accounts appears to be

> XXXXX@{projectId}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

you will probably not be able to create one with the old format just go with the new format

Comment: Thanks for your reply,, when I go ahead and use XXXXX@YYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com, PDI shows "Authentication failure occurred when contacting Google analytics. Please verify the credentials in the service account email and key file fields as well as your network connectivity." error. There's no problem with my network hence I believe the service account email has to be XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: And you granted the service account access to your Google Analytics account?   and you download the p12 file and not the Json file?

Comment: Yes you are right. Access was granted and p12 file was downloaded and pointed through PDI's google analytics source step.

Comment: If its still not working you will need to contact them directly they may have issues with the code because of the change in the format of the service account.